How to wait for a function in C# windows application to execute which is getting called from C# API project
I am novice to Task, threads and parallel programming and I tried
reading about it but I didn't understand how to fit solution to below
problem.
Basically I have a Function which is executing on users action.
private void HandleRequest(IWpointDestinationRequest wpointRequest)
        {
           //DoSomething
           
           ApiCalled(wpointRequest);
        }

What I am trying to achieve here is When I do some action on my UI I
can reach until HandleRequest(IWpointDestinationRequest wpointRequest) So far so good. No issues until here. However I have
an api project which is also calling
HandleRequest(IWpointDestinationRequest wpointRequest)
Functionality is with some user action
HandleRequest(IWpointDestinationRequest wpointRequest) will get
called from UI however wpointRequest.SendReply() should be executed
only when API calls HandleRequest(IWpointDestinationRequest wpointRequest). So I want to wait until API calls to
HandleRequest(IWpointDestinationRequest wpointRequest).

Many webpages have java scripts and the java is still running when the response is sent from server to client.  The only way of knowing when the java completes is to wait until data on the webpage goes from null to a non null value.

A function should only know what it must to perform it's task. It shouldn't need to know how it is called. Or even if it is compiled into a winforms / asp.net project. At best, use async / await so the function can run without blocking for IO operations.

Although this mostly depends on how your UI calls HandleRequest(), but here is a simple idea:
// when calling from UI, set isFromUI as true.
private void HandleRequest(IWpointDestinationRequest wpointRequest, bool isFromUI = false)
{
   //DoSomething

   if (!isFromUI)
     ApiCalled(wpointRequest);
}

This doesn't look like an API for other projects though, since it is private. If what you mean by API is a HTTP API endpoint, HandleRequest() and ApiCalled() should be separated, and only use ApiCalled() in the API endpoint, then the new boolean above isn't needed either.

Hello @Peko Miko,
Thank you for your answer. Actually I need to wait until  HandleRequest is getting called again from Api project. I have mentioned the steps in above comment. I hope it will clarify the workflow I am looking for.

For this you need to used async/await
so at first the ApiCalled function must be :
async Task<your type>(if it is void just place Task) FunctionName(IWpointDestinationRequest sth)  {

"calling api using await"
using(var client = new Httpclient()){
sth...
var result = await client.SendAsync();
var response =await result.content.ReadStreamAsync();
".....sth else..."
}

"On main method:"

private async Task HandleRequest(IWpointDestinationRequest wpointRequest, bool isFromUI = false)
{
 
    await ApiCalled(wpointRequest);
"Or if it has return type":
var result = await ApiCalled(wpointRequest);
}



}



Hello @Behtash,
Thank you very much for your reply. Actually "calling api using await" is not needed in Function you have mentioned as per my opinion. Basically I understood your HandleRequest method but The FunctionName function you have mentioned is bit confusing to me. because Here actually I am talking about 2 different contexts.


My Regular UI functionality is calling   HandleRequest for the first time which is working as of now.


Catch here is in the same context I get API call (which I am referring as 2nd Context)




Now FunctionName function has wpointRequest.SendReply which should be executed only when API calls HandleRequest.
So the flow is UI calls HandleRequest method and now APICalled function call should keep waiting until HandleRequest again gets a call from API project.
Why I need to wait is because my UI call has wpointRequest object filled which I need to use when API project calls HandleRequest.
I hope I am clear and not confusing you. :-)

